# 'int' object is not callable (python 2.7 server/client calculator)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

Okay, first off I know this question has been asked quite a few times, however, none of the previous questions have included the use of UDP sockets.
I've tested this code without using UDP sockets and it works just fine.
Thank you in advance, here's my code:

Client.py:

```
from socket import *
serverName = "localhost"
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
num1 = int(input("1st number: \n"))
func = raw_input("Function (+,-,*,/): \n")
num2 = int(input("2nd number: \n"))
clientSocket.sendto(int(num1), func, int(num2)(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print (modifiedMessage)
clientSocket.close()
```

Server.py:

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket ( AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM )
serverSocket.bind (( '', serverPort ))
print ('The Server is ready ')
while 1:
    num1, func, num2, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
if func =='+':
    modifiedMessage = num1 + num2
    else:
        pass
if func =='-':
    modifiedMessage = num1 - num2
    else:
        pass
    if func =='*':
        modifiedMessage = num1 + num2
    else:
        pass
    if func =='/':
        modifiedMessage = num1 / num2
    else:
        pass
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File"C:\Users\Myhat2you\Desktop\client.p", line 8, in         clientSocket.sendto(int(num1), func, int(num2)(serverName, serverPort))  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Could you post the _exact_ error your getting directly in your question?

Comment: `int(num2)(serverName, serverPort)` is suspicious. but a traceback would be welcome...

Comment: When asking about an Exception that your program produces, you should post the complete Traceback - it has clues in it, like which line caused the problem.  Did you try to [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect the variables by printing them?  Are they what you expceted?

Comment: This is the error I got: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting a problem here I'm still new to how I should communicate the issue I'm having.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File"C:\Users\Myhat2you\Desktop\client.p", line 8, in <module> clientSocket.sendto(int(num1), func, int(num2)(serverName, serverPort)) TypeError: 'int' object is not callacble

Comment: What exactly you expect a value of `int(num2)(serverName, serverPort)` to be, and why?

Comment: clientSocket.sendto(int(num1), func, int(num2)(serverName, serverPort)) is intended to send those inputs (num1, func and num2) to a local server.

Comment: But wait, we're not talking at all about sending. To call `clientSocket.sendto` Python first needs to figure out values for all arguments. It's fairly easy to check value of `int(num1)` and `func`, but what'd be a value of `int(num2)(serverName, serverPort)`. Forget for now about sending to socket. Your interpreter does not do it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is indeed here:

```
clientSocket.sendto(int(num1), func, int(num2)(serverName, serverPort))
```

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/librarysocket.html#socket.socket.sendto), `sendto` accepts `str`, not `int`, `str` and `int`.

However, traceback You got is there because You tried to call some `int` value as function (say `num2` is `"5"`, then, `int(num2)` will be `5`, and You're calling `5(serverName, serverPort`).

If You want to send those values to server, I suggest one of the following:

1) send them one by one

2) send them as string separated by some special character (ie. `|`)

Comment: Any idea how I could send num1, func and num2 to the server to respond with a calculation?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out!